# Regex to pick a value from url

Tags: regex

I am having difficulty to build a regex which can extract a value from the URL. The condition is get the value between after last "/" and ".html" Please help

Sample URL1 - https://www.example.com/fgf/sdf/sdf/as/dwe/we/bingo.html - The value I want to extract is **bingo**

Sample URL2 - [www.example.com/we/b345g.html](http://www.example.com/we/b345g.html) - The value I want to extract is **b345g**

I tried to build a regex and I was able to get "bingo.html" and "b345g.html using `[^\/]+$` but was not able to remove or skip ".html"

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

`\/([^\/]+?)(?>\..+)?$`

Explaination:

- `\/` - literal character '/'
- `([^\/]+?)` - first group: at least one character that is not a '/' with greedyness (match only the first expansion)

  - `[^\/]` - any character that is not a '/'
  - `+` - at least one occurence
  - `?` - greediness operator (match only first expansion)
- `(?>\..+)?` - second optional group: '.' + any character (like '.html' or '.exe' or '.png')

  - `?>` - non-capturing lookahead group (exclude the content from the result)
  - `\.` - literal character '.'
  - `.` - any character (except line terminators)
  - `+` - at least one occurence
  - `?` - optionality *(note that this one is outside the parenthesis)*
- `$` - end of the string

If you want also to exclude query strings you can expand it like this:

`\/([^\/]+?)(?>\..+)?(?>\?.*)?$`

If you also need to remove the protocol part of the url you can use this:

`(?<!\/)\/([^\/]+?)(?>\..+)?(?>\?.*)?$`

Where this `(?<!\/)` just look if there are no '/' before the start of the match

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work if I have https in the URL

Comment: @Gopi edited for protocol part

Answer (score 1):

You are only matching using `[^\/]+$` but not differentiating between the part before and after the dot.

To make that different, you could use for example a capture group to get the part after the last slash and before the first dot.

```
\S*\/([^\/\s.]+)\.[^\/\s]+$
```

- `\S*\/` Match optional non whitespace chars till the last occurrence of `/`
- `([^\/\s.]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times any char except a `/` whitespace char or `.`
- `\.` Match a dot
- `[^\/\s]+` Match 1+ times any char except a `/` whitespace char or `.`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BNTvye/1).